# SharePoint 2010 cascade delete with multivalued lookup column

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lookup

I have a sharepoint list which has a lookup column to fetch data from another list. I want this lookup column to allow multiple values but the problem is that SharePoint 2010 disables the "Enforce Relationship behavior" checkbox when i choose to allow multiple values in the column. I want the item to be deleted from this list as well when it is deleted from the parent list. What would be the least complex way to achieve this in the minimum time. I know that we can create a Visual Studio Workflow to achieve this but if there is a better solution which requires least customization or even SharePoint designer 2010 please share.

Answer (score 2):

Standard SharePoint lookup does not support it. You can develop custom solution using event receivers to delete related items or or use this add-on: http://www.sparqube.com/sharepoint-lookup-column.

Answer (score 1):

Ria,

Can't do this OOTB but you can create a custom solution. Create an extra column where you track information about your lookups (e.g., the ID of the related item). Use an event receiver on the list and programmatically do the cascade delete.

Comment: if you're still around and need a follow up i'm more than happy to help when i'm off work, just let me know.